# generating unique string for each java object instance

Tags: java

I need to write a function which returns a string which should be unique for each state of the object.

i.e. if any of the instance variables are changed, then this method should return another string which should be unique for the given set of instance variables of object.

Similarly I would later require write another method which represents unique static state of the class.

Please suggest any efficient ways to achieve my requirement.

Thanks,
Harish

Comment: What is the purpose of ur function?

Comment: every object instantiated is unqiue and can be differiente by JVM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to track the changes to a given object's state (in its own boundary), this is achievable with a bit of coding or adopting an already implemented approach. Is that what you are asking? What does make using an incrementing serial number inappropriate in your case?

If you are about to guarantee uniqueness amongst all the existing instances of a given class, this is a bit hard. You might need to distinguish an object individually, then asking each object for their unique string representation.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend reading about Object.hashcode(). The ideas recommended for [hashcode generation](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=28) could be used for the purpose you want.

Comment: +1 The best way to go. If you need a String, `Integer.toString(obj.hashCode())`

Comment: -1 a hashcode, while often based on the member variables of a class, is not unique or intended to be unique. Good hashing algorithms provide for sparse distributions of hashcode values, but don't make any guarantee that collisions won't occur.

Comment: @TimBender is correct. 
I did not say that using the hascode directly would solve the problem and would not recommend that. But I'd think understanding hashcode generation would be useful to create this required unique String.

Comment: Wrong answer. If only I knew hashes are not unique when I was designing my system :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java reflection to find all the fields in your class and work from there:

```
public String tos() throws IllegalAccessException {
    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
    for (Field f : getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
        f.setAccessible(true);
        b.append(f.get(this));
    }
    return b.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A fairly naive approach would be to serialize the object to memory and take a secure hash of the content.  Quite inefficient but it works with any serializable object.

What are the requirements exactly?

- Do nested objects also affect state (or is this applicable)?  if a.b.c changes does this affect state of a?
- Do two different objects with the same content have to end up with the same string?